# How to shopify storefront navigation menu get with API?

Tags: shopify, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

If anyone can please help me with how to retrieve the navigation menu with REST and Graphql API.

If no API is available, then how can I write a custom Navigation API?

We need to get the below data with API. [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXGji.png)

Comment: Can you explain your question with more details? with some code of what you actually are trying to do?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot. please check I need to retrieve this data

Comment: @Ankit Dholiya how you achieve this please mention in answer so it will help you to more people

Answer (score 6):

Use this in query. it worked for me. Remember to replace "main-menu" with the header code of your site.

```
{
  menu(handle:"main-menu"){
   items{
    id
    tags
    title
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore. I'm getting the following error: Field 'menu' doesn't exist on type 'QueryRoot'. It's odd though this is still documented here: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/storefront/2023-10/queries/menu.

Answer (score 0):

currently, there is no API endpoint that would allow you to access the navigation. However, seeing that the navigation in your screenshot mainly contains collections, probably it would be a good starting point for you to read those? This can actually be done via this call:

```html
GET /admin/api/2020-01/collection_listings.json
```

You can find more info here:

https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/sales-channels/collectionlisting#index-2020-01

Hope this helps,
Roman